# JQuery when using dynamically created child divs - float: left loses the child divs

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, css-float, parent-child

Hi I've tried a number of different methods to try and work this problem but I'd like your help please.

I have a a css formatted but empty SECTION that I'm trying to dynamically create a layout within using JQuery when a button is clicked.

This is my html section:

```
<SECTION ID="Section_Article_1">
<P CLASS="header">Title</P>
</SECTION>
```

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){    
            var topStyles = {
            backgroundColor : "#69830E",
            color: "#ffffff",
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: "",
            textAlign: "center",
            marginTop: "-20px",
            };
            $("#Section_Article_1").append("<div id = 'title'><p>Header</p></div>");
            $("#title").css(topStyles);

            var leftColumn = {
            backgroundColor : "#ffffff",
            width: "30%",
            height: "500px",
            color: "#000000",
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: "",
            marginTop: "-20px",
            float:left,
            paddingLeft: "2px",
            };
            $("#Section_Article_1").append("<div id = 'left'><p>Left Column</p></div>");
            $("#left").css(leftColumn);

            var rightSection = {
            backgroundColor : "#000000",
            width: "70%",
            height: "500px",
            color: "#ffffff",
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: "",
            textAlign: "center",
            marginTop: "-18px"
            };
            $("#Section_Article_1").append("<div id = 'right'><p>Right Section</p></div>");
            $("#right").css(rightSection);

        });
    });
```

When I run the function my "title" div appears fine as I want it, but the other two are not there. When I remove the "float: left" from my second div, they both appear but are displayed one on top of the other.

I'm trying to get my title bar to display across the top, then my other two to be beneath it with my second div "left" to display on the left and the third div "right" to display on the right next to "left"

I tried setting my containing section to display:inline but it didn't work either.

How can I display my "left" div and "right" div inline without them disappearing? Thanks

Comment: We seem to be missing some html from your sample, is everything included?

Comment: In the interest of troubleshooting your layout issues you should use jsFiddle or Bootply (http://bootply.com/60455) to separate out the HTML and CSS and see what's going wrong. It's hard to do CSS layout via jQuery.

Comment: @Xotic750 I also have some css for my section and the section itself is contained within an ARTICLE. I can add these later if necessary. Skelly thanks for the links I'll check those out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a javascript error with the style "float:left" - it needs to have quotes around "left"

```
float:"left"
```

otherwise, it thinks you're referring to a variable named 'left'.

Comment: jamauss is correct (http://jsfiddle.net/T9H9T/). @Kyohei Kaneko also remove the last comma from each line in topStyles, leftColumn, and rightSection as older versions of IE throw errors when the last declaration has a comma after it :)

Comment: @Jamauss I'm sure I tried that already but I'll double check later on. Just off out to a meeting.

Comment: Hey - why do you think it magically worked as soon as you removed "float:left" from the second div? ;) Because it contained a syntax error - not because the CSS was bad.

Comment: My friend you're a genius ;) I must have tried it with some other problems. Thanks